# How can I mount one end of a pullup bar to a brick wall and the other end to a stud wall?

Tags: walls, load-bearing

I want to install a pull-up bar in my hallway between two walls. The distance, wall to wall, is approx. 39" and I have a 1" steel pipe and wall flanges.

My concern is that while one of the walls is an external brick wall, the other is an internal stud wall. I have located the beam, but my questions are:

1. Is this a suitable place in my apartment to fit the pull-up bar? (or is it never advisable to use stud walls given the heavy load expected on the bar?), and
2. What wall plugs/screws should I use? Specific length, width, etc.? And do I also need washers of some kind?

[image]
[image]

Comment: @MadMonty care to delete that comment and add a new one that finishes the thought? :D

Comment: @crip659 Thanks, the flanges are 3.5" in diameter so you're right it wouldn't be possible to do all four holes drilling straight (maybe top, bottom, and one side if I set it off center to the beam). Do I need specific types of wall plugs/screws? Any recommendations about this would be very helpful. Also, are you saying that it's not advisable to screw into brick on the other side? (that's the opposite of what I thought the issue would be!)

Comment: @JonCuster when you say 'using multiple studs' do you mean that the 2x4 should run along the wall so I can affix it to two beams in the wall? That'd mean a piece of 2x4 approx 1.5ft long on the wall?

Comment: Yes, across multiple studs. Just how long depends on where the studs are and where you want the bar to be.

Comment: Thanks -- makes sense. Do you think this is the only safe way to do it? (It wouldn't look the nicest and this is a finished room, so that'd be something i'd consider). Also, on the other side, where the wall is brick, there'd be no point in doing that right? On that side, i can just screw the flange directly into the wall?

Comment: The 2x4 across studs can be painted/stained to make it look good/part of the the wall.  Can also get fancy and shape the edges.

Comment: I see no brick. What's over it? How thick is it?

Comment: The brick is on the right-hand side of the photo (the side with the light). I don't know how thick the plaster is. I'd expect not very, maybe 0.25"

Comment: Thanks a lot @crip659. I'm not opposed to this but just want to check that there is no safe alternative. In your view is it unsafe to fix the flange directly into the stud? (3 screws directly into the stud and the fourth into the plasterboard with some sort of special wall plug). This would preferable as long as it's safe as i've already got the steel pipe cut to spec and don't have tools myself to make it shorter (which i'd need to if I have a bit of 2x4 in between the pipe and wall)

Comment: The screws should be close to the centre of the stud.  Placing screws near the edge, trying to place three screws, might split the edge if too close and lose the holding power.  You only have 1.5 inches of width to play with, with ~ three inch circle of holes.  Drywall/plaster will only be good to hold the screw in place, not holding weight.

Comment: Having spoken with someone else about this, i think i'm going to cut a hole in the dry wall, add in an additional 2x4 vertical stud to increase the width of the existing stud and give a larger base to screw the flange onto. Then ofc, make good with the wall

Comment: Your better bet, @C.Robin, would be to put blocking between 2 studs and use that to screw the bar into. That's essentially what Jon Custer said, but hiding the board behind the drywall instead of putting it on the surface.

Comment: What do you mean by blocking? 2x4 running horizontally?

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/57620/how-much-weight-can-a-2-inch-screw-in-a-wood-stud-hold